# How can I hide small values from a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to show only values of >=2. Is it possible to hide everything below 2 or above -2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by [extracting the data from the graph](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2607-excel-extract-data-from-chart.html#a1) an then creating a new graph with that data minus small values